# Linq to sql select db_id()

Tags: linq-to-sql

How to make query for db_id() in Linq to SQL. PLease help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You even can map method to the standard function. Add following code in the dbml and use `dataContext.DbId()` (you can use it inside query also):

```
<Function Name="db_id" Method="DbId" IsComposable="true">
  <Return Type="System.Int32" />
</Function>
```

Comment: Thank you oryol. Nice tip. I applied this and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Expose it as a function or stored procedure.